# How do I script retrieval of file from memory cache of Firefox?

Tags: python, browser, scripting, webdriver

In general I am interested in browser automation with a focus on browser control as opposed to web page interaction. Specifically, I am looking for a macro recorder or a driver (webdriver? or Marionette?) that can be scripted to navigate about:cache on Firefox in the following sequence:

about:cache/Information about the Network Cache Storage Service>memory/List Cache Entries>Information about the Network Cache Storage Service/[right click on a key, open in new tab]>Cache Entry Information/[right click on the key, Save Link As...]

The Network tab of the Firefox Web Developer tool often shows transferred files that are cached but invisible to disk viewing utilities. Is there an approach that can automate the process of accessing a file cached in memory and saving it to disk?

Edit:  It appears that the key given in about:cache?storage=memory does not access memory for retrieving the file, but sends a new HTTP request. The manual method for saving a transferred file described above using the about:cache key does not work when the network connection is disabled. The problem of accessing memory remains.

Comment: maybe it needs `PyAutoGUI`, `pynput` or `pyautowin` which can control mouse and keyboard - so they can click on elements and send text to field. But maybe it keeps this information in some file ? Firefox keeps some information (like bookmarks, history) in database SQLite.

Comment: @furas--PyAutoGui and pyautowin show promise for control by mouse clicks at static locations on some of the pages but the Information about the Network Cache Storage Service page has variable content and has to be searched for the item of interest.

Comment: `PyAutoGUI` can use `image` to recognize element's location